# node-inspector looking for <module>.js when 'require'd

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-inspector

I am getting started with Node Inspector (Linux Mint 14). When I try to debug a simple .js file - `console.log("Hello World")` - with:

```
node-debug app.js
```

Node Inspector starts as expected, breaks on the first line and runs to completion on 'resume'.

However if I include a 'require' in my app.js:

```
require('someModule');
console.log('Hello World);
```

NI breaks ok, but when I 'resume' it throws a 'file not found' error as it can't find a .js file with the node module name in node_modules, i.e. `./node_modules/someModule.js`. Although there is a `./node_modules/someModule/someModule.js`.

Can anyone see what I'm missing?

Comment: try running npm install once

Answer (score 0):

Doh! Whilst I was clicking around I'd clicked on the "pause on all exceptions" button in the bottom left corner. Clicked on this again and it's now ignoring all the exceptions thrown as it looks for the module files.